# Trying to use async/await instead of browser.sleep, but it does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, async-await, protractor

I am new to protractor and starting with automated testing of an angular app. I have one test, where I need to use multiple browser.sleep() to actually wait for the elements to render and click on them. With the browser.sleep() it works fine, but when I try to use async/await, the test fails, because it does not wait for the element.

I did set the SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false, before I use the async/await

This one works:

```
browser.get(http://localhost);
browser.sleep(1000);
element(by.cssContainingText('.title1, 'text1')).click();
browser.sleep(1000);
element(by.cssContainingText('.title2', 'text2')).click();
```

This one does not work and says the second element could not be found:

```
it('should navigate to screen', async function() {
    browser.get(http://localhost);
    browser.wait(function () {
      return element(by.css('.top-navigation')).isPresent();
    }, 5000);
    await element(by.cssContainingText('.title1', 'text1')).click();
    await element(by.cssContainingText('.title2', 'text2')).click();
  });
```

Comment: I don't know much about Protractor, but does thi `element(...).click()` return a promise? If not, the `await` operator won't do much.. It can only await a promise.

Comment: add `await` before `browser.get(..)` and `browser.wait(..)`.

Comment: unfortunately adding `await` before `browser.get(..)` and `browser.wait(..)` did not help, the element could not be find....but the solution with _ExpectedConditions_ seems to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**await != wait**

await is used to queue promise-chained elements to add synchronicity. In your case, you should add waiting for the element before trying to interact with it. The easiest way is to create a function that waits for the element, then you pass whatever element you need, like so:

Declare the expected conditions:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
```

write the click function:

```
const clickElement = async function (element) {
    await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element));
    await element.click();
};
```

then use it:

```
it('should navigate to screen', async function() {
    await browser.get(http://localhost);
    await clickElement(element(by.cssContainingText('.title1', 'text1')));
    await clickElement(element(by.cssContainingText('.title2', 'text2')));
});
```

Comment: Yup, you still need to await a browser.wait. This is a great answer!

Comment: @radoja glad it helped! please mark it as correct so others can also benefit from it

Comment: Nice answer, better than a tute.